# How can I use yq with a variable for array index when traversing a YAML file in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, yq

Given the yaml file `test.yaml`:

```
- alpha
- bravo
  - one
  - two
- charlie
- delta
```

How do I find the `i`th element in the array? For example:

```
i=2
```

Then `array[$i]` should return `charlie`.

I am using Mike Farah's `yq`.

If I try

```
yq '.[$i]' test.yaml
```

I get not the `i`th element in the array as expected, but rather the entire array! Output:

```
alpha
bravo - one - two
charlie
delta
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You're using single quotes in `yq '.[$i]' test.yaml`, and single quotes inhibit shell variable expansion. What happens if you use double quotes?

Comment: @larsks that could possibly work, but I recently learned that using double quotes with yq injects data into the code and is bad practice. I just now found that environment variable operators are needed with yq to use variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following the [yq documentation for environment variable operators](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-string-environment-variable), we can use the variable `$i` like this:

```
i=$i yq '.[env(i)]' test.yaml
# alpha
```